# Error installing PostGIS for PostgreSQL on Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgis

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL with its PostGIS extension on Mac. The installation happens in two parts : 1) PostgreSQL and 2) PostGIS through the stack builder. The first phase goes smoothly, but the second phase returns the following error at the beginning of the installation of PostGIS:

[image]

[image]

I trying installing it with the latest version of PostgreSQL as well (version 12), and I get the same error. Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have the same issue when I install PostGIS by Stack Builder on MacOS.
After many times trying to install/uninstall PostGIS. Finally, I installed it successfully by manual installation.
I think this issue caused by your MacOS doesn't have or conflict in the default app for extracting .zip file.

**I have fixed it by install manually, like the following:**

- Download PostGIS by Stack Builder as usual
- Open the folder where you have downloaded PostGIS (often it is `/Users/yourUserName`)
- Extract the PostGIS zip file (the file name like this: `edb_postgis_...`)
- Install PostGIS app

Finally, everything is done! You have installed it successfully!

Comment: This is the only answer of many which worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: You saved my days, weeks.....

Comment: On macOS Ventura this worked - `edb_postgis_2_5_pg12.app.zip` was located in `/Users/myUserName`.  Unzipped with `unzip` and then opened the extracted app `postgis-pg12-2.5.5-1-osx`.

Comment: What a simple solution, it worked!!

Comment: The file edb_postgis_... is getting deleted by default. Could not find it in the said directory. Any other solution?